# QEMU not flushing drive changes to host filesystem

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker, qemu

I am running a simple efi shell within QEMU and I wish for the files to persist between QEMU launches, namely NvVars. I am trying to understand why changes are only flushed after I create several files.
After some investigation I found this [neat article](https://www.heiko-sieger.info/qemu-system-x86_64-drive-options/) and then experimented with caching.
This is how I'm trying to launch QEMU, albeit with no success:

```
-drive file=fat:rw:/partitions/partition1,format=raw,cache=none \
```

Edit:
After posting I started changing the contents of this "/partition1" folder with the second volume expression:

```
    -v "$(CURRENT_DIR)/partitions/":"/partitions/" \
    -v "$(CURRENT_DIR)/Build/OvmfX64/DEBUG_GCC/X64/UefiTools/":"/partitions/partition1/UefiTools/" \
```

And it started being flushed out, but only sometimes if there's a change within UefiTools. This is to say, `NvVars` is sometimes only updated if something outside QEMU writes to it.
If no files change within `UefiTools`, the mounted volume by docker won't show up in my fs even though they show up inside QEMU.

In other words, the problem might be due to Docker and not QEMU.

Comment: What's `fat:rw:/partitions/partition1`? (And are you really running it on Linux as you tagged?) By NvVars do you mean those in your virtual UEFI firmware (OVMF)? If so, what's the argument you use to attach it to your VM? Maybe share the full command line?

Comment: I think you're right @Tom Yan, there was more to this than QEMU as it is running inside a docker container.